google translate api error 401 in React Native project
I created an account via cloud for Google Translate, created an API key and got the credentials information. Api url works without any problems in Postman. I also created a react.js web project to test it and it works fine there too. However, when I integrate my React Native application, it gives an error and terminates the session in my application. I log in to my chat application again and try it, the same thing continues. [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/8nLEsBTK.png)
const handleTranslate = async () => {
    try {
      const translatedConfessionText = await translateText(
        selectedConfession.confess,
      );
      const translatedTitle = await translateText(selectedConfession.title);
      setTranslatedConfessionText(translatedConfessionText);
      setTranslatedTitle(translatedTitle);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error translating text:', error);
    }
  };

  const translateText = async text => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=********',
        {
          q: text,
          source: 'tr',
          target: 'en',
        },
      );
      return response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error translating text:', error.response.data);
      throw error;
    }
  };


<Text style={styles.modalText}>
              {translatedConfessionText || selectedConfession?.confess}
            </Text>

There is no problem with web or postman.
enter image description here

This is indeed curious.
It's confusing that Google provides 2 endpoints translation/translate
And the documentation (Supported Features) for translation.googleapis.com Basic v2 does include that it supports API Keys but I think it (no longer) does.
The Translating text (Basic) documentation includes a REST example that requires a POST method and requires OAuth:
PROJECT="..."

# If you have gcloud CLI installed
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

curl --request POST \
--Heade "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--Header "x-goog-user-project: ${PROJECT}" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2

So, I think you should definitely consider using a Client SDK (includes auth too) rather than raw REST but, I think (!?) you'll need to consider using OAuth (per the error message) and see Set up authentication

I tried the same api url link by creating a new react native project and it does not give an error there. I didn't make any changes on the google cloud side either.

I tried the same api url link by creating a new react native project and it does not give an error there. I didn't make any changes on the google cloud side either.
This application translates without errors with the same URL.
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=******";

const translateText = async (text, targetLanguage) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}`, {
    q: text,
    target: targetLanguage,
  });

  return response.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
};

export default translateText;

